# split() issues with pdf extractText()

Tags: python, pdf, text

I'm working on a minor content analysis program that I was hoping that I could have running through several pdf-files and return the sum of frequencies that some specific words are mentioned in the text. The words that are searched for are specified in a separate text file (list.txt) and can be altered. The program runs just fine through files with .txt format, but the result is completely different when running the program on a .pdf file. To illustrate, the test text that I have the program running trhough is the following:

"Hello 
This is a product development notice
We’re working with innovative measures
A nice Innovation
The world that we live in is innovative
We are currently working on a new process
And in the fall, you will experience our new product development introduction"

The list of words grouped in categories are the following (marked in .txt file with ">>"):

- innovation: innovat
- product: Product, development, introduction
- organization: Process

The output from running the code with a .txt file is the following:
[image: .txt output]

Whereas the ouput from running it with a .pdf is the following:
[image: .pdf output]

As you can see, my issue is pertaining to the splitting of the words, where in the .pdf output i can have a string like "world" be split into 'w','o','rld'. I have tried to search for why this happens tirelessly, without success. As I am rather new to Python programming, I would appreciate any answe or direction to where I can fin and answer to why this happens, should you know any source.

Thanks

The code for the .txt is as follows:

```
import string, re, os
import PyPDF2
dictfile = open('list.txt')
lines = dictfile.readlines()
dictfile.close()
dic = {}
scores = {}
i = 2011
while i < 2012:
    f = 'annual_report_' + str(i) +'.txt'
    textfile = open(f)
    text = textfile.read().split() # lowercase the text
    print (text)
    textfile.close()
    i = i + 1
    # a default category for simple word lists
    current_category = "Default"
    scores[current_category] = 0
    # import the dictionary
    for line in lines:
        if line[0:2] == '>>':
            current_category = line[2:].strip()
            scores[current_category] = 0
        else:
            line = line.strip()
            if len(line) > 0:
                pattern = re.compile(line, re.IGNORECASE)
                dic[pattern] = current_category
    # examine the text
    for token in text:
        for pattern in dic.keys():
            if pattern.match( token ):
                categ = dic[pattern]
                scores[categ] = scores[categ] + 1
    print (os.path.basename(f))
    for key in scores.keys():
        print (key, ":", scores[key])
```

While the code for the .pdf is as follows:

```
import string, re, os
import PyPDF2
dictfile = open('list.txt')
lines = dictfile.readlines()
dictfile.close()
dic = {}
scores = {}
i = 2011
while i < 2012:
    f = 'annual_report_' + str(i) +'.pdf'
    textfile = open(f, 'rb')
    text = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(textfile)# lowercase the text
    for pageNum in range(0, text.numPages):
        texts = text.getPage(pageNum)
        textfile = texts.extractText().split()
        print (textfile)
    i = i + 1
    # a default category for simple word lists
    current_category = "Default"
    scores[current_category] = 0
    # import the dictionary
    for line in lines:
        if line[0:2] == '>>':
            current_category = line[2:].strip()
            scores[current_category] = 0
        else:
            line = line.strip()
            if len(line) > 0:
                pattern = re.compile(line, re.IGNORECASE)
                dic[pattern] = current_category
    # examine the text
    for token in textfile:
        for pattern in dic.keys():
            if pattern.match( token ):
                categ = dic[pattern]
                scores[categ] = scores[categ] + 1
    print (os.path.basename(f))
    for key in scores.keys():
        print (key, ":", scores[key])
```

Comment: Extracting text from a PDF is not as straightforward as you seem to believe. "Why" words are broken up is not something we can answer – not even if you *did* provide a link to your PDF. Why? Because the software that created it, chose to render a word in two or more parts. Why that? Because there is some kerning between these letters. Why not use the built-in kerning features then? We can only guess – et cetera.

Comment: Thanks, that was actually very enlightening. In the quest for knowing more, I'll dig deeper on the rendering of words and the kerning between the written letters when dealing with .pdf fies.

Comment: To put things into (even more) perspective: consider yourself lucky you get *any text at all*. All plain 'text' in a PDF may be encoded, compressed, and encrypted (zero or more of each of these). In regular text files, there is an unbreakable link between the numbers in the file and the text on your screen: `0x61` is *always* going to show up as `a`. In a PDF file, that no longer needs to be the case. Bottom line: never read from a PDF if you also have access to the original data.

Comment: I have no experience with extracting text from PDF, but you might want to try different tools to extract the text from your PDFs. Some might put in more effort to properly extract words from "non-proper" PDFs (using a dictionary for example and/or analyzing spacing between these non-word words).